# having been or had been

Tags: grammar

All the flights____because of the snowstorm, we had to take the train instead.

A. were canceled      B. had been canceled

C. having canceled     D. having been canceled

Here is an exam question maded by Chinese education department?I guess. The correct answer is D and I asked one of my American friends,he thought both A and B are making sence.

Comment: This is a horrible question if you've copied it correctly. Your friend is right and the exam "correct" answer is wrong. Can you check the question again or have you written it from memory?

Comment: @Catija Yeah.. I'm pretty sure that I've copied it correctly. They explain that "comma" in English cannot separate two full sentences. If we use "were canceled" or " had been canceled", both of them will make the first part a full sentence. So that's why D is the correct answer. But it's really weird to use "having been canceled" in this sentence.

Comment: @iBug I'm sorry but I don't know a single native speaker who would say "All the flights having been cancelled..." The reason I'm saying the sentence is wrong is because it's absurdly contrived. We would say "All the flights were cancelled because of the snowstorm so we had to take the train instead".

Comment: @Catija While I agree with your assertion that no native speaker would use "All the flights having been cancelled..." in conversation, I can see it being used in something like a retelling or account of a day's events. I agree it's still a bad question, but there is a context where the "correct" answer would make sense to me.

Comment: @Catija - This native speaker would say it.  It's not "absurdly contrived" in the least.  You would  be quite likely to find a sentence like that in a newspaper.

Comment: It may be true that A and B would require a punctuation change, but I’m with @Catija – “D” sounds stilted and I wouldn’t recommend that any learner actually talk that way.

Comment: @J.R. The question is about grammar. The first part being longer than expected doesn't make the sentence ungrammatical. Neither A nor B are grammatical, and punctuation matters, so I don't see how Catija's comment works there at all. I don't care if they corrected themselves later, that comment is upvoted and first even though it's completely wrong as is. The other comment they made is perfectly fine and shows what they really meant—their experience and opinion as a native speaker. This wouldn't matter if everyone read every comment and if everyone were a computer with no *first impressions*.

Comment: @userr2684291 - Perhaps the question is about grammar (or maybe it's just tagged that way? It's hard to know for sure). In any case, I try to be mindful that leaners peruse these pages for various reasons, and think it's worth pointing out when the "correct" answer on a test would sound unnatural in a conversation – even though it may be grammatically correct.

Comment: @J.R. Haha, let's be reasonable: Catija has stated the same in another comment so her valuable advice won't be lost. It's only misleading to have a native speaker authoritatively say it's wrong to say D and correct to say A or B, when neither of those is, in point of fact, correct. Upvotes on comments are worth zilch, so no loss there either. I see absolutely no reason why that comment should stay. Furthermore, you have two other native speakers saying the sentence is okay, contradicting that comment. What's it gonna be?

Comment: @J.R. The question is actually asking about the correct answer to that question. Maybe the correct answer is always D, by definition, and it's got nothing to do with English. Are we going to shake the premise of the whole thing, rendering this question unanswerable?

Comment: @userr2684291 -- Where did I say this question was unanswerable? Where did I say that D was not the right answer? All I said was that "D" sounds stilted.

Comment: @J.R. Oh, no, you actually endorsed the first comment. You can water it down all you want as many times as you want (we had *wrong*, then *absurdly contrived*, then *stilted in casual conversation*), but you agreed with it **as it is** and left it extant – which is what I asked about. Do you understand *wrong* as "correct but stilted in casual conversation"? If you don't, then why in the world would you agree with it? If you don't know whether the sentence is *correct*, how can you agree with it? I guess *reasonable* is unidiomatic in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background: I am a Chinese student learning English like mad.

First of all, I eliminated both option A & B because there's only one single sentence, so if A or B *were used*, there needs to be a conjunction after the comma (`...snowstorm, so we...`). Therefore the former part of the sentnece **must be a dependent clause**. A comma should never separate two full sentences.
Now look at option C and D. The flights **were canceled**. They can't cancel themselves, so a passive voice should be used. Thus, "having been canceled" fits best here in the given scenario.

**Extras**: Why not use "being canceled"? Because event "the flights are canceled" happened **before** "we have to take the train", and it's a prerequisite of "we take the train". The two things happened one by one, so a perfect tense is used here.

Comment: Thanks man, you helped me alot.I am also a Chinese English learner but I am not a student anymore. Our country kept cultivating a bunch of grammar experts rather than people speak like native speakers. Sad story~

Comment: @Bevis But when I discuss things on Stack Exchange and Reddit, I don't care about grammar, either, leaving whatever I've learned from school behind.

Comment: @Bevis If you check out [Chinese.SE], you'll find non-native speakers learning Chinese just like we learn English.